# Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I am working on an AZURE function.The purpose of the function is to
calculate the status of a module: fail, pass condoned, pass or pass with distinction. when I run the code I get this error.I get an error at mark because it is an integer.

```
Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=90c68ac4-4bc1-4446-9ad4-2b15e8ea8a00, Duration=145230ms)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.
```

The class:

```
class MarkEntry
{
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
}
```

}

The Azure function takes 4 inputs and checks if the student has a condoned pass or not:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            MarkEntry obj = new MarkEntry();
            string responseMessage ="";
            string respmaessage="";
            string result="";
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            obj.StudentNumber = req.Query["studentnumber"];
           obj.Name = req.Query["name"];
           obj.Module = req.Query["module"];
            obj.Mark =Convert.ToInt32(req.Query["mark"]);


            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            obj.StudentNumber = obj.StudentNumber ?? data?.name;
            obj.Name = obj.Name ?? data?.name;
            obj.Module = obj.Module ?? data?.name;
           obj.Mark = obj.Mark.ToString() ?? data?.obj.Mark.Tostring();







            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.StudentNumber))
            {
                respmaessage = "Enter a student number";
                return new OkObjectResult(respmaessage);

            }


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Name))
            {
                respmaessage = "Enter a student Name";
                return new OkObjectResult(respmaessage);

            }
         
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Module))
            {
                respmaessage = "Enter Student Module";
                return new OkObjectResult(respmaessage);

            }


            if (obj.Mark<49)
            {
                result = "Condoned Pass";

            }

            responseMessage = string.Format($"Student Number: {obj.StudentNumber}" + "\n" +
$"Student Name: {obj.Name}" + "\n" + $"Student Mark: {obj.Mark}" + "\n" +
$"Student Module: {obj.Module}" + "\n" + $"Student Result: {result}"
                );
              

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);

        }
    }
```

Comment: line **Convert.ToInt32(req.Query["mark"]);** seems to be causing the problem. Check what are you receiving in **req.Query["mark"]**

Comment: AN Integer is received under req.Query["Mark"]

Answer (score 0):

The `MarkEntry` class has the `Mark` property defined as an integer type.  In the azure function we instantiaite this class. ...

`MarkEntry obj = new MarkEntry();`

and then later on line 13 or so of the function ...

`obj.Mark = obj.Mark.ToString() ?? data?.obj.Mark.Tostring();`

It looks like we are attempting to assign a string value to this integer.
Not sure this will work?